# ItemAdding list field

Tags: event-receivers, event-handlers

I am trying to update list field using ItemAdding,

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {


        SPListItem curListItem = properties.ListItem;
        curListItem.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; // This property should be set to true for the update to go through
        curListItem["Age"] = "";
        curListItem.Update(); // This line should update the ListItem but it doesnt

    }
```

UPDATE

```
  public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

        string empty = "";
        properties.AfterProperties["Age"] = empty;
        base.ItemAdding(properties);

    }
```

Comment: You are using `ItemAdding` not `ItemUpdated` in the code.

Comment: I wrote wrong i mean ItemAdding will update

Answer (score 1):

Use `properties.AfterProperties["Age"] = "Your Value";`

See [Set custom field value in ItemAdding event](http://aanuwizard.com/2010/06/set-custom-field-value-in-itemadding-event/) for more information.

Comment: I have a custom list in a teamsite, what should i have in elements.xml for the list ? i have right not ListUListUrl="sites/test/Drafts" on that url is my list?

Comment: `<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">`

Comment: i will update, my code thas not clear item added column

Comment: Try setting a debug point. Make sure your code is getting executed.

Comment: yes it enters my itemadding but the field does not get empty

Comment: Try putting null or string.empty instead of "".

Comment: Testing with a list, this works for me. It's of course different for a Document library.